# Finding Candidate Keys / Superkeys

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relation, candidate-key

I am working on another question here and it asks for the candidate keys and the superkeys.  I believe I have the correct candidate keys, but if someone could verify that would be great.  I am also just having trouble finding superkeys.  I don't know if there is a general formula to find them or whatnot.

Here is the question:

```
Relation Schema: U(A,B,C,D)

FD's: 

A-->B

B-->C

C-->D

D-->A
```

I found the Candidate keys to be: {A},{B},{C},{D}.  If someone could verify if this is correct, I would greatly appreciate it.  Also if you could let me know how to find the superkeys of this, that would be great.  I am not looking directly for the answers, I just want to know if my answer for the candidate keys is correct and how to find the superkeys for this and possibly other questions (if there is a generic way to find them).

Hope someone can help.  Will rate best answer once someone helps me figure this out.

Cheers everyone.

Comment: http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/sql-first-second-and-third-normal-forms.html?

Comment: That did not help for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain how to find candidate keys in a simple manner:

Form a three columns,**left,right and middle**

> In left column,add the attributes which appear only on **left** hand side of FD
>
> In right column,add attributes which appear only on **right** hand side of FD
>
> In middle column,add attributes which appear **both** on right and left hand side of FD

Explanation:

> Attributes on left column indicates,every possible candidate keys must include these attributes

and

> Attributes on right column indicates candidate keys should not include it

and

> Attributes on middle may or may not be included in super keys

In the given example,
All the attributes come under **middle** column

Then,apply **Closure property**,

> **A+=ABCD**

since

> A->A **Reflexivity rule**
>
> A->B **given**
>
> A->C **Transitivity rule** A->B and B->C
>
> A->D **Transitivity rule** A->B and B->C and C->D

Similarly,we can show other keys also as Candidate keys.

**Super keys** are nothing but a superset of candidate keys and non-prime attributes

Thus,your answer is **right**

And super keys of this relation is a super set of candidate keys,therefore

Super keys are **AB**,**AC**,**ABC** and so on.

Hope this helps.